# How can I install the Mosquitto-php in Laradock

Tags: php, mosquitto, laradock, libmosquitto

Mosquitto-php extension: https://github.com/mgdm/Mosquitto-PHP.

I tried to add 2 below commands in the laradock/php-fpm/Dockerfile, but it didn't
work.

```
apt-get install libmosquitto-dev && \
pecl install Mosquitto-alpha
```

please give me some advices, thanks.

Comment: To be able to help you you may want to specify wich error messages you have seen and give more feedback to your environment. (Server Version, php version and so on...)
Also this question also may be migrated to serverfault.com

Comment: @finder2 Thanks your suggestion, I will provide more details about the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try add this in dockerfile:

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
        libfreetype6-dev \
        libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
        libpng-dev libxml2-dev libcurl4-gnutls-dev \
        libmosquitto-dev # edit


RUN docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) mysqli mbstring pdo pdo_mysql soap curl \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/ \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd \
    && pecl install xdebug && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug \
    && pecl install Mosquitto-alpha && docker-php-ext-enable Mosquitto-alpha
```

Comment: It works, many thanks. I add this commands in Dockerfile and build the php-fpm again.  `RUN apt-get install -y libmosquitto-dev && \
          pecl install Mosquitto-beta && \
          docker-php-ext-enable mosquitto`